# Converting DVD (VIDEO_TS) to MP4 (h.264/h.265) using VLC plays only audio or video but not both

Tags: mp4, dvd, vlc

Opening the converted .mp4 file with windows 10 mediaplayer doesn't play the audio but does play the video.
Opening the converted .mp4 file with the same VLC used to convert the DVD to MP4 doesn't play the video but does play the audio.

Answer (score 0):

Posted this question as I wanted to share my answer to this. I found that customizing the audiocodec used for the `Video - H.264 + MP3 (MP4)` profile to `MPEG 4 Audio (AAC)` from the default `MPEG Audio` fixed the issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Actually.. this caused audio and video to both play but they went out of sync, thus this didn't solve my problem.